# cannot access a development server on a server im ssh'd into

Tags: django, server, centos

I am deploying a django app from a Centos server. When i do a `python3.6 manage.py runserver 8000` command it starts a development server no problem.  I am not able to access this page from my local computer to test it.

so the steps i take are: i ssh into the server by doing `ssh <user>@url.com` and then run the dev server with the above command.  I then go to the browser on my laptop and type url.com:8000 and will come up with `Unable to connect`

I also have this problem when running my apache server for production. i would have no problems putting up the server on the server im ssh'd into but cannot access the webpage.

I know this is very little information to go on but does this sound like a server side issue at url.com?  Should i be contacting the administrators with this, or is this something on my end possibly?

Maybe i need to configure the address my settings.py in my django app?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to run it so it listens on any interface. From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/django-admin/#runserver):

> Note that the default IP address, 127.0.0.1, is not accessible from
>   other machines on your network. To make your development server
>   viewable to other machines on the network, use its own IP address
>   (e.g. 192.168.2.1) or 0.0.0.0 or :: (with IPv6 enabled).

By example, you should start the server with 
`python3.6 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`

In general, it is probably not wise to keep such a thing running on the web, particularly with debug on. From the same documentation link:

> DO NOT USE THIS SERVER IN A PRODUCTION SETTING. It has not gone
>   through security audits or performance tests. (And that’s how it’s
>   gonna stay. We’re in the business of making Web frameworks, not Web
>   servers, so improving this server to be able to handle a production
>   environment is outside the scope of Django.)

Comment: Yeah i do understand this, but when i run the apache serve i get the same problem so i was seeing if there was something wrong with the configuration by also running the test server to see if i was able to get to it from there

Comment: What error do you get? are you adding the port in your browser's url?

Comment: Yes the port is added, it just says unable to connect, no errors... i am able to get a server up and do it that way(but that has errors) but for this it won't